# Does Super Dragon Ball Heroes Universe creation arc have a manga version?

Tags: dragon-ball-heroes

Super Dragon Ball Heroes Prison Planet arc and Universal Conflict arc animes had a manga version of them.
How about Super Dragon Ball Heroes Universe creation arc ?

Does Super Dragon Ball Heroes Universe creation arc have a manga version?

Answer (score 1):

I found.    https://dragonball.fandom.com/wiki/Super_Dragon_Ball_Heroes:_Universe_Mission_(manga)   there and random chapters at other sites. Im not thinking its official, but seems popular